# Max number of push notification that is shown in lock screen iOS9

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios9

On the iOS9, I noted that all of the notifications are not being seen on the lock-screen. It seems like after a large amount of notifications the lock screen preview will only show some of them. Does anyone know that is there a limit on the max number of notifications shown in lock screen per app, since I am not seeing all of them in the lock screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can see maximum **10** recent notification on the lock screen. You can change the setting for a particular application. By going to iOS Settings-> Notification-> Select any application-> Show in notification center.

Comment: Is it different for all apps? Because I was able to see more than 35+ notifications on lock screen for Inbox app. It is not limited to 10.